# How do I add SQS IAM for my Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

I was able to get this to work with the serverless.yml:

```
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "sqs:SendMessage"
        - "sqs:ListQueues"
      Resource: "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:*:*"
```

But I want to apply it only to a certain function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/), you need to create the function role under `resources` and reference this new role inside your function.

Example:

```
service: my-test

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10

functions:
  hello:
    role: mySQSRole
    handler: handler.hello

resources:
  Resources:
    mySQSRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: mySQSRole
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: myPolicyName
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2012-10-17'
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - sqs:SendMessage
                    - sqs:ListQueues
                  Resource: "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:*:*"
```